# PHP: Timestamp difference incorrect

Tags: php, timestamp

**The situation**

I've got two timestamps. 
One with the start time and one with the end time.

The start time is: 04:43:37
The end time is: 11:59:59

Now I am trying to get the difference between the dates like this:

```
//define timestamps
$start_time     = 1297698217;
$end_time      = 1297724399;
$time_diff    = $end_time - $start_time;

//display times and difference
echo 
    '<b>Start time:</b> ' . date('d-m-Y h:i:s', $start_time) . '<br />' .
    '<b>End time:</b> ' . date('d-m-Y h:i:s', $end_time) . '<br />' .
    '<b>Time difference::</b> ' . date('h:i:s', $time_diff);
```

**The result**

```
Start time: 14-02-2011 04:43:37
End time: 14-02-2011 11:59:59
Time difference: 08:16:22
```

**The problem**

Now the problem is that the result should be 07:16:22. I've tried this with different times, but every time I'm getting the same result. One hour too much difference.

Is there an expert willing to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last one should be `gmdate` instead of `date`:

```
'<b>Time difference::</b> ' . gmdate('h:i:s', $time_diff);
```

`date` adjusts for your current locale, which appears to be GMT+1.  `gmdate` does not make that adjustment.

I'm assuming that you're only planning to use this for time differences less than 24 hours.

Comment: I do not really understand why I have to set gmdate() only for the difference. I have three timestamps. Is the last one different?

Comment: The last one is not a timestamp, it's a time difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it to turn 1970-01-01 07:16:22 into a time string for display - there are going to be differences based on your time zone.

To make it a GMT date use gmdate() but this will still cause you issues when time differences get >24 hours.