# PHP Hours, Mins and Seconds between 2 Timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp

PHP 4

```
$a = 1359994013   (Mon, 04 Feb 2013 16:06:53)
$b = 1359997483   (Mon, 04 Feb 2013 17:04:43)
```

How do I calculate the difference between these two timestamps and shows the results as:

```
w days, x hours, y mins, z seconds.
```

Eg :
0 days, 0 hour, 58 mins, 10 seconds

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you already tried? Hint: You do realize that both timestamps are simple integer values that you can substract from one another?

Comment: This post should be able to help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018152/php-timestamp-difference-incorrect

Comment: PHP 4? Really? You seriously haven't upgraded your server since 2007? (would it help if I pointed out all the security flaws in PHP4?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

This should work if you have PHP4

Comment: PHP 5 includes [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), which will solve your question in a simple one-liner. But meh, if you can't upgrade then you can't upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are into the calculation and insist on using PHP 4:

```
$a = 1359994013;
$b = 1359997483;

$difference = $b-$a;

$second = 1;
$minute = 60*$second;
$hour   = 60*$minute;
$day    = 24*$hour;

$ans["day"]    = floor($difference/$day);
$ans["hour"]   = floor(($difference%$day)/$hour);
$ans["minute"] = floor((($difference%$day)%$hour)/$minute);
$ans["second"] = floor(((($difference%$day)%$hour)%$minute)/$second);
echo $ans["day"] . " days, " . $ans["hour"] . " hours, "  . $ans["minute"] . " minutes, " . $ans["second"] . " seconds";
```

This gives you `0 days, 0 hours, 57 minutes, 50 seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the date function:

http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php